# Make some of the fonts aliased

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-10.10, anti-aliasing

I would like to use aliased fonts in my IDE (geany), while still using anti-aliased fonts in other applications. I remember doing this for emacs (unfortunately I don't remember how I did that). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick would be to override your IDE's display font settings to a custom settings that your ide is setup as...  in a configuration file.

Xft is the rendering method of the fonts used by GNOME and also by other Xft-aware applications.

In order to configure Xft for the other applications you should configure the file .Xresources in your home directory like that:

```
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.hinting: 1
Xft.hintstyle: hintfull
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
```

:)